# Could't add resources into fullcalender (dayview) i want to split 8 colunm per day

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using jQuery 2.0.0+, Moment 2.9.0+ in my project. I am unable to add resources into dayview.  This is my coding

```
schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
defaultView : 'agendaDay',
defaultDate : '2018-04-07',
editable : true,
selectable : true,
eventLimit : true, // allow "more" link when too many events
header : {
    left : 'prev,next today',
    center : 'title',
    right : 'agendaDay,month'
},
views : {
    agendaTwoDay : {
        type : 'agenda',
        duration : {
            days : 2
        },

    //groupByDateAndResource: true
    }
},

//// uncomment this line to hide the all-day slot
allDaySlot : false,

resources : [ {
    id : 'a',
    title : 'Room A'
}, {
    id : 'b',
    title : 'Room B',
    eventColor : 'green'
}, {
    id : 'c',
    title : 'Room C',
    eventColor : 'orange'
}, {
    id : 'd',
    title : 'Room D',
    eventColor : 'red'
} ],
  events: [
      { id: '1', resourceId: 'a', start: '2018-04-06', end: '2018-04-08', title: 'event 1' },
      { id: '2', resourceId: 'a', start: '2018-04-07T09:00:00', end: '2018-04-07T14:00:00', title: 'event 2' },
      { id: '3', resourceId: 'b', start: '2018-04-07T12:00:00', end: '2018-04-08T06:00:00', title: 'event 3' },
      { id: '4', resourceId: 'c', start: '2018-04-07T07:30:00', end: '2018-04-07T09:30:00', title: 'event 4' },
      { id: '5', resourceId: 'd', start: '2018-04-07T10:00:00', end: '2018-04-07T15:00:00', title: 'event 5' }
    ],
```

Comment: it won't start displaying the resources until you uncomment the line "groupByDateAndResource: true". See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view

Comment: if you're having some other problem apart from that, you'll have to make clear what it is. "Unable to" doesn't give us any clue. Instead tell us about unexpected behaviour, any console error messages etc you may be seeing. Maybe make us a JSFiddle demo to show your problem happening. Thanks.